# Pygame Game Menu Finding the Rect Position

Tags: python, pygame

```
class menu:
    hover = False
    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.set_rect()
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        self.set_render()
        screen.blit(self.render, self.rect)

    def set_render(self):
        self.render = subFont.render(self.text, True, self.get_color())

    def get_color(self):
        if self.hover:
            return (BLACK)
        else:
            return (GREEN)

    def set_rect(self):
        self.set_render()
        self.rect = self.render.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos



select = [menu("Computer Virus", (100, 200)),
          menu("Computer Crime", (100, 300)),
          menu("QUIT", (100, 400))]

running = True
while running:
    for evnt in event.get():  
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill(WHITE)    
    title()
    for menu in select:
        if menu.rect.collidepoint(mouse.get_pos()):
            menu.hover = True               
        else:
            menu.hover = False
        menu.draw()
    pointer()
    display.update()
```

This is my game menu where hovering over will allow you it to change colour
Im planning to make it so the that when you click on one of the options, it would bring you elsewhere. How do I find the position of the rect and with which text it the mouse collides with?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. We need to be able to execute it to get the problem and test around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you want:

```
class menu:
    hover = False

    def __init__(self, text, pos, callback):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.callback = callback # so we now what function to call
        self.set_rect()
        self.draw()
    # the rest of your code

def quit_loop():
    global running
    running = False
select = [menu("Computer Virus", (100, 200), lambda: print("Computer Virus")), # Add a callback
          menu("Computer Crime", (100, 300), lambda: print("Computer Crime")),
          menu("QUIT", (100, 400), quit_loop)]

running = True
while running:
    for evnt in event.get():
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # if a mousebutton got pressed
            if evnt.button == 1: # if the first button got pressed
                for menu in select:
                    if menu.rect.collidepoint(evnt.pos): # does this one collide
                        menu.callback() # call the callback
```

Comment: How would I define which rect they clicked? I want to do something like `if menu.callback == quit(): running = False` but that just quits the whole program... how would I make it so it would only quit if you click the quit button?

Comment: @IanChan I edited a example on how to quit. But for your information: You should start programming OOP.

Comment: one last question: How would I make it so that lambda doesn't print something, but goes to the next screen? Kinda like a menu, where when you click on the button, it would go the next part of it. I tried adding a function and making lambda return the function, but the screen would refresh too fast and nothing would show up. The problem I'm having is that the screen would refresh to the original before showing me the new screen.